# How to use a synonym dictionary for full-text search in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

Currently, I'm playing a bit with full-text search in PostgreSQL. At the moment I have created a table that has a number of columns and one of that columns is of type tsvector in english configuration. This allows me to use full-text search using the following functions plainto_tsquery or to_tsquery.

I would like to expand my full-text search to handle a search through synonyms and/or check for misspelled words. I was digging through the internet and I couldn't find any example of how to setup a synonym dictionary (thesaurus would be a preferred option) or spell check functionality and where to find a comprehensive English synonyms dictionary.

Is there any tutorial that can guide me on how to achieve my goals?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try the documentation for the product you are using?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to look into docs, but the description of creating and using a thesaurus is based on some non-real world example. I would like to see an example of configuring an English thesaurus dictionary and applying it to process full-text search over some table .